# categories and number of items from each one

Tags: sql, select, count

I have this two tables:

```
ID       category_name 
-----------------------
1        Pizza       
2        Salad         
3        Desert         
4        Sandwiches


ID       name              category 
--------------------------------
1        Margherita          1
2        Quatro Stagioni     1     
3        Pancakes            3
4        Some Salad          2
```

I want to make a SQL statement which will get the name of the category and the number of products from each category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the two tables and group the result by the category:

```
SELECT   category_name, COUNT(*)
FROM     categories c
JOIN     products p ON p.category = c.id
GROUP BY category_name
```

Comment: I thought it will be more complicated.Thank you!
Should i delete the question beacuse it may be seen like a duplicate?